# In wso2 Dropbox connectors, getfile will get only xml files not get any other formats like .html, .doc

Tags: wso2-esb

****In wso2 Dropbox connectors, getfile will get only xml files not get any other formats like .html, .doc can u please tell me the answer i need all types of formats .**

Answer (score 1):

Please enable/add the relevant message builders and formatters in axis2 configuration (\repository\conf\axis2\axis2.xml).
eg : For HTML files you need to add the following message builder and formatter.

```
   <messageFormatter contentType="text/html" class="org.wso2.carbon.relay.ExpandingMessageFormatter"/>
   <messageBuilder contentType="text/html" class="org.wso2.carbon.relay.BinaryRelayBuilder"/>
```

Please find more details in [documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Configuring+Message+Relay) and this [article](http://wso2.com/library/articles/binary-relay-efficient-way-pass-both-xml-non-xml-content-through-apache-synapse/).

Comment: can you please tell me the how to get javascript files

Comment: can you please tell me how to get javascript files, text files

Comment: Try with adding the following <messageBuilder contentType="text/plain" class="org.wso2.carbon.relay.BinaryRelayBuilder"/>
<messageBuilder contentType="text/javascript" class="org.wso2.carbon.relay.BinaryRelayBuilder"/>

<messageFormatter contentType="text/plain" class="org.apache.axis2.format.PlainTextBuilder"/>
<messageFormatter contentType="text/javascript" class="org.wso2.carbon.relay.ExpandingMessageFormatter"/>

Comment: <TryitProxyError xmlns:h="http://wso2.org/ns/TryitProxy" h:status="SOAP envelope error">org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Read timed out</TryitProxyError>

Answer (score 0):

In addition to that we are doing a new connector to support latest drop box api version. Use the following link to followup.

https://wso2.org/jira/browse/ESBCONNECT-105